# how do I log crash to the server without try-catch block?

Tags: java, try-catch, effective-java

I do not understand when to use try-catch , and what is wrong with them ,special this item (57 java-effective)
could someone explain this

```
 // Horrible abuse of exceptions. Don't ever do this!
try {
   int i = 0;
   while(true)
      range[i++].climb();
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
}

for (Mountain m : range)
   m.climb();
```

> "Because exceptions are designed for exceptional circumstances, there is little incentive for JVM implementors to make them as fast as explicit tests.
> Placing code inside a try-catch block inhibit certain optimizations that modern JVM implementations might otherwise perform.
> The standard idiom for looping through an array doesn’t necessarily result in redundant checks. Modern JVM implementations optimize them away."

Finally, if we cannot use try-catch in each block , how can I log crashes to the server without catch block

Comment: It doesn't say not to use try-catch blocks. It says not to use them in place of "explicit tests". i.e. in this case use traditional for-loop `for (int i = 0; i < range.length; ++i)`. It's not a fantastic example. Essentially what they are getting at is to not use exceptions for normal flow control but only for **exception**al circumstances.

Comment: I posted an answer with explanation and example, did it help you?

Comment: @Steyrix thank you , but you do not answer all of my questions

Comment: Do you mean "how can I log crashes to the server without catch block"? Since it is the only question I did not answer

Comment: Please specify your problem, so we will be able to help you

Comment: @Steyrix , item 57 said "Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions" , How can I take a control over all my methods , so every crash is logged to the server

Comment: It's actually another question, but you CAN use try-catch for this purpose, it is up to you where you want to surround your logic with try-catch. It also dependent on your stack of technologies, logic of crash tracking is different in different technologies (e.g. Android/Spring etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use try-catch, but you should never abuse it. Avoid [**exception-driven development**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_by_exception).

You should use try-catch only to catch exceptions that you cannot predict as a developer, for example - getting invalid response from server (since you are not responsible for backend, you don't know anything about server's implementation and its' response sending mechanisms).

In the example above, handling `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` is pointless, since you can avoid exception by rewriting `while`-loop condition as `while(i < range.size() - 1)` or not using `while`-loop at all and using `for`.